How to avoid logs duplication in a logger having several appenders?
I want to distribute logs to several files depending on a flag in the LoggingEvent. Let's say all log lines with the flag valued to "A", must go to A.log, those with value "B", must go to B.log, etc. There is a 'default' file default.log in which logs with values other than "A" or "B" should go.
I made a filter that accept/deny the log depending on the flag. I use it this way :
<appender name="A" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    ...
    <filter class="...FlagFilter">
        <flag>A</flag>
    </filter>
</appender>
<appender name="B" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    ...
    <filter class="...FlagFilter">
        <flag>B</flag>
    </filter>
</appender>
<appender name="Default" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    ...
    (no filter there)
</appender>

My problem is that the default file catches all the A and B lines.
I can not define several loggers using the "additivity=false", as they would require names and I do not want to filter the logs by their package.
So, is there a way to avoid logs duplication in a logger having several appenders?
The only way I can imagine is having a 'reverse filter' for the default appender, in which I will have to declare A, B, etc being refused, which will be a pain as there are a lot of possible values.
